Added Christoffel Symbols in geodesic equation having different units
I am trying to find the Kerr geodesic equations for light rays using the Boyer-Lindquist version of the metric:
$$ ds^2=-(\frac{r_sr}{\Sigma}-1)c^2dt^2+\frac{\Sigma}{\Delta}dr^2+\Sigma d\theta^2+(r^2+a^2+\frac{r_sra^2}{\Sigma}\sin^2{\theta})\sin^2{\theta}d\phi^2-\frac{2r_sra\sin^2{\theta}}{\Sigma}dtd\phi $$
There's this issue where added Christoffel symbols in the geodesic equation don't have the same units. As an example of one of the equations:
$$ \hat{e_t}\frac{dv_t}{d\lambda} = -[(\Gamma^r_{tt}\hat{e_r} + \Gamma^\theta_{tt}\hat{e_\theta})v_t + (\Gamma^t_{tr}\hat{e_t} + \Gamma^\phi_{tr}\hat{e_\phi})v_r + (\Gamma^t_{t\theta}\hat{e_t} + \Gamma^\phi_{t\theta}\hat{e_\phi})v_\theta + (\Gamma^r_{t\phi}\hat{e_r} + \Gamma^\theta_{t\phi}\hat{e_\theta})v_\phi]v_t $$
Ignoring basis vectors and comparing $ \Gamma^r_{tt} $ and $ \Gamma^\theta_{tt} $ via dimensional analysis:
$$ \Gamma^r_{tt} = \frac{r_sc^2\Delta(r^2-a^2\cos^2{\vartheta})}{2\Sigma^3} $$
Units of $ \Gamma^r_{tt} $ = $ ms^{-2} $
$$ \Gamma^\theta_{tt} = -\frac{r_sra^2c^2\sin{\theta}\cos{\theta}}{\Sigma^3} $$
Units of $\Gamma^\theta_{tt}$ = $ s^{-2} $
It gets even worse when considering the basis vectors:
Units of $ \Gamma^r_{tt}\hat{e_r} $ = $ m^2s^{-2} $
Units of $ \Gamma^\theta_{tt}\hat{e_\theta} $ = $ s^{-2} $
Do I ignore the units of these terms in the calculations? And if I do not, what parameters/variables are suitable to ensure the units are the same?

It should be clear from the definition of the Christoffel symbols (in terms of the metric tensor) that they all have the same units. There must be a mistake in your calculations.

Something is wrong about the metric you wrote, the first term is lacking an overall quadratic form as coefficient.

When the coordinates $(t,r,\theta,\phi)$ have different units, then the metric components $g_{\mu\nu}$ will have different units too, and hence the Christoffel symbols as well. This is very common in GR and no problem at all, because the geodesic equations are still consistent.

The geodesic equation is $\ddot{x}^m = - \Gamma^m_{kl}\dot{x}^k\dot{x}^l$. So I do not understand that you have on the left side an upper $t$-index and on the right side Christoffel symbols whose upper index varies, it is not always $t$. That should not be the case. Check this equation.

Note that from @FredericThomas's version of the geodesic equation, the units of $\Gamma^m_{kl}$ should be $[x^m]/[x^k] [x^l]$, where $[x^m]$ denotes "the units of $x^m$."  This is consistent with your results for $\Gamma^r_{tt}$ and $\Gamma^\theta_{tt}$.
